# why algebraic numbers form a field?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

of course the problem is how to prove if `a` and `b` are both algebraic `real` numbers then `a+b` and `ab`
is also an algebraic number .

would you explain it without using vector spaces or extensions or etc.
things we know are :

1. there exists a polynomial which its root is a
2. there exists a polynomial which its root is b

please just keep it simple!

Comment: You may find [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) useful.

Comment: It's so much easier to use vector spaces. It's the simple approach. The complicated approach is to insist on finding polynomials for $a+b$ and $ab$.

Comment: Because the set of algebraic numbers is the union of all algebraic extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$: for any algebraic $a$ and $b$ there is a finitely generated extention that contains them both, and the union of fields is again a field. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to show it is to see first that any element generates a finite extension if and only if it is algebraic, and that the degree of field extension is monotone and multiplicative. Both facts are rather straightforward.

Then just pick any $a,b$ algebraic, and notice that $[{\bf Q}(a,b):{\bf Q}(a)],[{\bf Q}(a),{\bf Q}]$ are both finite, therefore $[{\bf Q}(a,b):{\bf Q}]$ is finite as well, and by monotonicity so is $[{\bf Q}(a+b):{\bf Q}]$ as well as $[{\bf Q}(ab):{\bf Q}]$.

Answer (score 1):

If you like Galois theory let $a_1, \ldots a_n$ be the conjugates of $a$ and 
 $b_1, \ldots b_m$ be the conjugates of $b$ then the polynomial

$$\prod_{i,j} (x-(a_i+b_j))$$ is invariant under all automorphisms and so its coefficients lie in the ground field.